# Sorting an array of vectors in decreasing order while using a comparator (C++)

Tags: c++, sorting, oop, c++11, vector

I have a vector of Car* objects in them that point to an object that has an id and position attribute. I want to sort the vector in decreasing order by position (i.e., the highest position at vector[0] etc.).

Here is the sorting and comparator code below:

```
bool comparator(Car* firstObject, Car* secondObject) {
    return firstObject->get_position() > secondObject->get_position();
}

void sortingFunction(vector<Car*> arrayOfCars) {
    sort(arrayOfCars->begin(), arrayofCars->end(), comparator);
}
```

I tried to use the std::reverse() method, but (and I could be wrong) I saw it only really works with numberical vectors rather than object vectors. Would enumeration be a way to use the reverse method or is there a way for me to somehow add the greater functionality to the sort function with the comparator?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is a C++ question, then why the `c` language tag? Please don't spam with unrelated tags.

Comment: 1) Why do you need `std::reverse`? Is your comparator not sorting in the order you wanted? 2) `std::reverse` works with any container that provides bidirectional iterators. The type of objects stored in `std::vector` doesn't matter.

Comment: And [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) doesn't depend on the contents of the container.

Comment: And why first sort in one way and then reverse the sorting? Why not sort the correct way immediately?

Comment: i misread the question and had to delete my answer. What is actually wrong? Why do you want to use `std::reverse` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sorting function is invalid.  For starters the vector should be passed by reference. And the vector is passed not through a pointer. So you may not apply the operator `->` to it.

So the funcion definition will look like

```
void sortingFunction( vector<Car*> &arrayOfCars ) 
{
    sort( arrayOfCars.begin(), arrayofCars.end(), comparator );
}
```

The comparator can be written with these minor changes

```
bool comparator( const Car *firstObject, const Car *secondObject) 
{
    return firstObject->get_position() > secondObject->get_position();
}
```

In this case the member function `get_position` must be a constant member function that is declared like

```
T get_position() const;
                 ^^^^^
```

where `T` is the return type of the function.

Comment: You don't NEED to use `const` in the comparator. The `vector` is not `const`, and it does not contain `const` pointers. If `get_position()` is not already `const`, then don't use `const` in the comparator. But if `get_position()` is `const` then by all means, use `const` in the comparator.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If pointed data is not changed in a function they always shall have the qualifier const.

Comment: that is *pteferred* when feisible, yes, but it is hardly *required*